# In TypeScript, how do I manually point to a library's declaration file .d.ts when manually importing a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, import

In my project I had a compile bug with vercel's `pkg` module when using `puppeteer-heap-snapshot`, which is fixed when manually importing `puppeteer-heap-snapshot/dist/cjs/src/index.js`

The bug is well described in this github issue, the only difference is the library that's being imported: https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/1694

Here's what I mean:

```js
// import { captureHeapSnapshot } from 'puppeteer-heap-snapshot'; // error when compiling, module not found
import { captureHeapSnapshot } from 'puppeteer-heap-snapshot/dist/cjs/src/index';
```

My problem is that when I import the javascript file like that, I have this warning: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'puppeteer-heap-snapshot/dist/cjs/src/index'.`

I know where the .d.ts files are located, they exist in the module folder. Is there a way to manually point to the .d.ts files in node_modules/puppeteer-heap-snapshot, so that I still get code autocompletion and this error goes away?

Comment: Probably not. The `.d.ts` file either declares a module with name `puppeteer-heap-snapshot` and its exported types, in which cases TS won't see them since you don't import `puppeteer-heap-snapshot` but some other module; or it exports all of the types and then the reference to `.d.ts` is set in `package.json` so that TS knows where to look for types when you import `puppeteer-heap-snapshot`, but you can't easily change it to a different module name.

Comment: And anyway it's a weird solution, what was the compile bug? Type error? If so changing to import `index.js` is not a fix, because you basically just disabled type checking for that module which is not a good way to go

Comment: Hi @AlexChashin, thanks. The problem is the exact same one described in this github issue, just with this library https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/1694
There is a tsconfig option called "paths" that allows us to remap imports. I wonder if I could tell it to look for the .d.ts like this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution with a small caveat, thanks to **Alex Cashin**'s comment under my question:

> TS won't see them since you don't import puppeteer-heap-snapshot but some other module

So the issue was that I was importing a module that, to the eyes of the linter, didn't actually exist. I managed to work around this issue by using the [paths option in tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths), to manually describe and point to the location of the library I'm importing - which to the linter is not `puppeteer-heap-snapshot` but `puppeteer-heap-snapshot/dist/cjs/src/index` instead.

The small caveat is that I have to edit tsconfig.json and add the path for this one library. The path is given relative to the location of the tsconfig.json file, or to the `baseUrl` setting if it is defined.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths" : {
      "puppeteer-heap-snapshot/dist/cjs/src/index": ["../node_modules/puppeteer-heap-snapshot/dist/types/src/index.d.ts"]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```